# Select random questions rows with decreasing order of difficulty

Tags: mysql

I have a situation here:
I am making a random online question paper system in which a user can select the difficulty levels starting from 0 to 5. Here is [Free anime streaming apps](https://www.techbynerd.com/top-10-anime-streaming-and-downloading-apps-for-iphone/).

There are approx 16k records in my question table and each question has its difficulty level from 0 to 5.
Now what i need is to get 10 random questions from 16k record with the difficulty level selected by user.

```
SELECT question,id from questions where difficulty = '5'
```

this is working fine but there is a situation when there are less than 10 question with difficulty 5. in that case i need to select other questions with difficulty level 4 and if again there are no question with difficulty level 4 then it must retrieve questions with difficulty level 3 and so on to make 10 question visible to the user.

What should i do ?? i need a SQL query!
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT question,id 
from questions 
order by difficulty = 5 desc, 
         difficulty desc,
         rand()
limit 10
```

Comment: You may have to remove `where difficulty = '5'` from the query. It will retrieve only the rows having `difficulty = '5'`.

Comment: HEllo @juergend this query is working good but it is not retrieving the rows with difficulty level 5.

Comment: Are you sure? What is it retrieving?

Comment: it is giving me rows with difficulty level lower than 5 but not 5

Comment: It is totally working for me. I just tested it. If you still think it does not work, then please edit your question and add example data and the output you get.

Comment: The only thing you could add is that if you want questions with diffculty `3` and not above that then add the `where` clause `where difficulty <= 3` to get questions with `3,2,1` and not above

Comment: Its working i was doing something wrong :( .. thanks for the working query :)